# Cannot create a Pivot Table in pandas because < not supported between datetime and int, none of them are dtype datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pivot-table

I am trying to create a pivot table for sum and count based on a very large dataset,  however every time I try to create the pivot table I receive an error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'
```

The only thing is none of the columns in the pivot table are of datetime in my formula:

```
    unused_columns=df4.columns.difference(set(['MATERIAL_C']).union(set(['Cat'])).union(set({'ORDER_QUANTITY'})))
tmp_df = df4.drop(unused_columns, axis=1)
pivot_table = tmp_df.pivot_table(
    index=['MATERIAL_C'],
    columns=['Cat'],
    values=['ORDER_QUANTITY'],
    aggfunc={'ORDER_QUANTITY': ['count']},
    
)
pivot_table.set_axis([flatten_column_header(col) for col in pivot_table.keys()], axis=1, inplace=True)
df3_pivot = pivot_table.reset_index()
```

or I also tried:

```
countPivot = pd.pivot_table(data = df3,index = ["MATERIAL_C"],columns = ["Cat"],values = "ORDER_QUANTITY",aggfunc = "count")
```

I check the dtypes and they are:

```
SO-Item                      int64
MATERIAL_C                  object
ORDER_QUANTITY             float64
REQUESTED_DELIVERY_DATE      int64
DELIVERY_DATE                int64
Months                       int32
Cat                         object
```

Does anyone know how I can get this to work since creating the dataframe manually seems to take forever when I try and use normal pandas logic since it is very large. I can also send the dataframe if you have any ideas?

Comment: what is the 'cat' column, show a few data points?

Comment: The cat data column has values: Withing 12 months,Withing 24 months, Withing 36 months,Over 36 so there should not be any datetime arguments